# Dimensionality Issue on Pytorch Transformer

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I'm starting with Pytorch and I'm currently making an Attention model with a encoder-decored structure.
I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/intel-student-ambassadors/implementing-attention-models-in-pytorch-f947034b3e66), and while I'm not getting any errors, there has to be an issue because I'm not getting the output tensor with the size needed, I have checked the code multiple times but I can't find the problem, maybe you can see something that I haven't seen.

This is the encoder:

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F


class Encoder(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = 32
        self.input_size = 16

        self.lstm = torch.nn.LSTM(self.input_size, self.hidden_size)

    def forward(self, inputs, hidden):
        output, hidden = self.lstm(inputs, hidden)
        return output, hidden

    def init_hidden(self):
        # (num_layers * num_directions, batch, hidden_size)
        return (torch.zeros(1*1, 10, self.hidden_size),
                torch.zeros(1*1, 10, self.hidden_size))
```

And this is the decoder:

```
class AttentionDecoder(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(AttentionDecoder, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = 20
        self.output_size = 20
        self.vocab_size = 16
        self.batch_size = 64
        
        self.attn = torch.nn.Linear(self.hidden_size + self.vocab_size, 16)
        self.lstm = torch.nn.LSTM(self.vocab_size, self.output_size, batch_first=True) #if we are using embedding hidden_size should be added with embedding of vocab size
        self.final = torch.nn.Linear(self.output_size, self.vocab_size)

    def init_hidden(self):
        # (num_layers * num_directions, batch, hidden_size)
        return (torch.zeros(1, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size),
                torch.zeros(1, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size))

    def forward(self, decoder_hidden, encoder_outputs, inputs):
        weights = []
        for i in range(len(encoder_outputs)):
            weights.append(self.attn(torch.cat((decoder_hidden[0][0], 
                                              encoder_outputs[i]), dim=1)))
        normalized_weights = F.softmax(torch.cat(weights, 1), 1)
        attn_applied = torch.bmm(normalized_weights.view(-1, self.vocab_size, self.hidden_size), 
                                 encoder_outputs.view(-1, self.hidden_size, self.vocab_size))

        input_lstm = torch.cat((attn_applied, inputs), dim=1) #if we are using embedding, use embedding of input here instead
        output, hidden = self.lstm(input_lstm, decoder_hidden)
        output = self.final(output)
        return output, hidden, normalized_weights
```

Then I create the model in a new class:

```
class Model(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, bidirectional=False):
        super().__init__()

        self.encoder = Encoder()
        self.decoder = AttentionDecoder()
        
    def forward(self, inputs):
        a, b = self.encoder.forward(x.float(), self.encoder.init_hidden())
        a = a.view(20, 64, 16)
        output, z, w = self.decoder.forward(self.decoder.init_hidden(), a, x.float())
        return output
```

When training the model, I have two variables, `x` and `y`, with dimensions:

```
# (batch, seq_len, vocab_size)
x = torch.zeros([64, 10, 16])
y = torch.zeros([64, 20, 16])
```

Then I pass `x` to the model:

```
model = Model()
output = model.forward(x)
print(output.size())
# torch.Size([64, 26, 16])
```

And I need the model to output size `torch.Size([64, 26, 16])` instead, when do I have to pass the model the output `seq_len` (which is 20)?

Comment: Impossible to reproduce. The code snippets you provided are not executable. There are lot of errors about variables not defined in classes. Did you try to run the exact same code you provided with no errors?

Comment: @Alka You are right, I made some mistakes compying the code in my question, I have updated my questions, now you should be able to run the code without errors.

Comment: I tried solving the errors but there are way too many hard-coded dimension values. You first need to change the `init_hidden` method in your Encoder because that's where the error is starting, and after you need to change the `a.view(20, 64, 16)` to `a.view(20, 64, 32)`.  That means you're going to have to change the initializations of your linear layers, but I don't have enough context to understand what you should change it to.